# Order array of objects by attribute presence

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
vendors = [
           {
             name: "Junction"
           },
           {
             name: "Woodside",
             is_new: "on"
           },
           {
             name: "Midtown"
           }
          ]
```

What would be a better way ruby to order this array by presence of the attribute "is_new". I want the objects with "is_new" attribute to appear on the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method:

```
vendors.sort_by { |v| v[:is_new] ? 0 : 1 }
```

You simply need to create a "sort key" that each element uses and then the array is sorted as if those were the values. Any sortable value, like something numerical or string will work.

Comment: If `:is_new` could have a value `nil` or `false`, use `v.key?(:is_new)` (same as `v.has_key?(:is_new)`). It's not a bad idea to always use `key?` for checking for the presence of a key.

Comment: It could be the case that `is_new` is `"off"` or something like that, in which case a more robust `case` statement is probably necessary to interpret the various possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
vendors.select { |h| h.key?(:is_new) } + vendors.reject { |h| h.key?(:is_new) }
  # => [{:name=>"Woodside", :is_new=>"on"}, {:name=>"Junction"},
  #     {:name=>"Midtown"}]
```